Navigator.share() is not supported for Android Mobile Publisher app
I have two Mobile Publisher apps—one for Android and one for iOS—that share the same Experience Cloud site. While implementing a new feature that requires sharing text in MS Teams app, I discovered that the only method available is to use the navigator.share() API. However, this method is not supported in the Android app, as it doesn't function within the Android WebView.
Are there any workarounds to enable native device sharing on Android or something that allow share text to MS Teams app?
The flow should be as follows:

Launch the MS Teams app from our Mobile Publisher app (either via LWC or Visualforce).
When the user selects a channel or user within the Teams app, the message generated by our LWC should be automatically populated.

